# Does Mule 4 recommends not to use scripting languages like Groovy?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Mule 4 recommends to use DW as much as possible but are there any recommendations from Mule around not to use scripting languages like Groovy? If yes, what will be advantages to move everything from Groovy to DW. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not explicitly, but more likely than not, you'd be better served sticking with DW instead of Groovy, especially as it relates to data transformations and configuring components with the DW expression language.

DataWeave was a language specifically created to make data transformations easier. Groovy is a general-purpose programming language. I believe you should reach for the more specific tool if it's easy enough to get to (it is, in this case), and use the more general-purpose tools as necessary.

Advantages to move everything from Groovy to DW? Mule 100% supports DataWeave. You get:

- drag/drop transformations,
- syntax highlighting,
- previews of your transformations,
- easily specify input/output metadata,
- better guarantees that your transformations are deterministic (and therefore easier to test).

The list goes on and has grown dramatically from Mule 3 -> Mule 4.

All that said, there are certainly times where a language like Groovy is more appropriate, but it's rare in my experience.